# FATAL exception: setOnClickListener on a null object in Android Studio

Tags: exception, android-studio

I'm writing a basic word scramble app in Android Studio, and have gotten everything laid out and the methods working, but I'm getting a fatal exception when I send it to my debugger.

Here's my java:

```
package com.example.admin.androidwordscramble;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class WordScramble extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText playerEdit;
TextView textUpper;
TextView textInstruction;
Button buttonNew;
Button buttonPlay;
String playerInput;
char[] answerWord;
char[] playerWord;
char[] scrambledWord;
final String word1 = "APPLE";
final String word2 = "CLOVE";
final String word3 = "LEMON";
final String word4 = "ONION";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_word_scramble);
    initControls();    //Where my logcat says the first error is.
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_word_scramble, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

void initControls() {
    playerEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.playerEdit);
    textUpper = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textUpper);
    textInstruction = (TextView)findViewById((R.id.textInstruction));
    textUpper.setText("Scramble Game");

    buttonNew.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()    //Where the logcat says the second error is.
    {
        public void onClick
                (View v) { newGame();}});
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {public void onClick
                (View v) { playGame();}});
}

void newGame() {
    playerEdit.setText("");
    answerWord = toArray(word1);
    shuffle(answerWord);
    textUpper.setText(scrambledWord.toString());
    textInstruction.setText("Unscramble it!");
}

void playGame() {
    playerInput = playerEdit.getText().toString();
    playerWord = toArray(playerInput);

    if(testWord()) {
        textUpper.setText(answerWord.toString());
        textInstruction.setText("Correct!");
    }
    else {
        textInstruction.setText("Incorrect. Try again!");
    }
}

char[] shuffle(char[] answerWord) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    char[] scrambledWord = new char[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < scrambledWord.length; i++)
        scrambledWord[i] = answerWord[i];

    final int max = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        int k = rand.nextInt(scrambledWord.length);
        int j = rand.nextInt(scrambledWord.length);
        char temp = scrambledWord[k];
        scrambledWord[k] = scrambledWord[j];
        scrambledWord[j] = temp;
    }
    return scrambledWord;
}

boolean testWord() {
    final int max = 5;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < max) {
        if (playerWord[i] != answerWord[i])
            return false;
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

    char[] toArray(String wordString) {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(wordString);
    char[] wordArray = new char[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        wordArray[i] = wordString.charAt(i);
    }
    return wordArray;
}
}
```

My XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".WordScramble">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="NEW"
    android:id="@+id/buttonNew"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="47dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PLAY"
    android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonNew"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="47dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Unscramble it!"
    android:id="@+id/textInstruction"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonNew"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="167dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/playerEdit"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonNew"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Try here"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:capitalize="characters" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textUpper"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textInstruction"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp" />
```

Log cat states:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.admin.androidwordscramble, PID: 2405
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.androidwordscramble/com.example.admin.androidwordscramble.WordScramble}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            ....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.admin.androidwordscramble.WordScramble.initControls(WordScramble.java:67)
            at com.example.admin.androidwordscramble.WordScramble.onCreate(WordScramble.java:36)
```

I've cleaned and rebuilt a couple times, but it still crashes the emulator and spits out an exception in the debugger. Can anyone point out where I went wrong with the button pointing?

Edit: Logcat for when the app froze:

```
    07-29 14:39:00.168      627-653/? E/ActivityManager﹕ ANR in com.example.admin.project03 (com.example.admin.project03/.WordScramble)
    PID: 1782
    Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 2.  Wait queue head age: 13282.2ms.)
    Load: 0.95 / 0.57 / 0.23
    CPU usage from 7918ms to 0ms ago:
    99% 1782/com.example.admin.project03: 99% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3756 minor
    2.6% 627/system_server: 0.1% user + 2.5% kernel / faults: 77 minor
    1.2% 250/vinput: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
    0.1% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    0% 96/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
    0% 245/healthd: 0% user + 0% kernel
    0.1% 254/local_gps: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    0% 783/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
    25% TOTAL: 24% user + 0.6% kernel + 0.3% softirq
    CPU usage from 2350ms to 2858ms later:
    101% 1782/com.example.admin.project03: 101% user + 0% kernel / faults: 200 minor
    98% 1782/admin.project03: 98% user + 0% kernel
    1.8% 1797/GCDaemon: 1.8% user + 0% kernel
    5.8% 627/system_server: 1.9% user + 3.9% kernel / faults: 3 minor
    1.9% 639/FinalizerDaemon: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
    1.9% 645/SensorService: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
    1.9% 653/ActivityManager: 1.9% user + 0% kernel
    26% TOTAL: 25% user + 1% kernel
07-29 14:39:00.338     627-1830/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
07-29 14:39:00.338      627-653/? D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
07-29 14:39:00.437     627-1830/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-29 14:39:00.437     627-1830/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xafc9b9a0, tid 1830
07-29 14:39:00.532      627-645/? D/Sensors﹕ Client connection accepted (186)
07-29 14:39:00.632     627-1830/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-29 14:39:00.644     627-1830/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-29 14:39:00.644     627-1830/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xafca9480, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Edit2: Added a while statement to prevent a crash if playGame was called, but now getting a FATAL NullpointerException right at the while statement.

```
void playGame() {
    while (answerWord != null) {
        playerInput = playerEdit.getText().toString();
        playerWord = toArray(playerInput);

        if (testWord()) {
            textUpper.setText(answerWord.toString());
            textInstruction.setText("Correct!");
        } else {
            textInstruction.setText("Incorrect. Try again!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `buttonNew` and `buttonPlay` are never initialized before calling the `setOnClickListener`, you need to add `findViewById` statements, to get a handle to the buttons in the view, giving them the same `id` in XML as the variable name does not give you the handle. So, before setting the `OnClickListener` you need to add ::

```
buttonNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNew);
buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
```

Just like you did for `playerEdit`, etc.
All the variables are initialized `null` by default, so without finding the view, you are calling `setOnClickListener` on `null` object, and hence the exception.

Comment: Thanks, that took care of the button problem. Now I've got a NoSuchElementException in my toArray() method, when I assign wordArray[i] to the character I've read from the string. I've initialized the array and the string I've passed is 'final', so I'm a bit confused as to why I'm getting this exception.

Comment: Okay, fixed the NoSuchElement by adding a while(hasNext()) condition, but now the entire app hangs when I use the newGame() button. Logcat says: "Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." I don't think this app should be using that much resources.

Comment: @fluffywarthog is there any other exception in the logcat after that?? Because I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001873/skipped-32-frames-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread and it actually turned out to be a NULL pointer exception at the end.

Comment: @fluffywarthog : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21126690/4106624 Take a look at this as well. This might help

Comment: posted my logcat from the most common error, and getting a new NullPointerException when I added a while statement to playGame().

Comment: @fluffywarthog : why do you create a `Scanner read` in `toArray` function?? And how do you exit the while loop of `playGame` you don't seem to modify `answerWord` in the while loop!

Comment: Thank you. Changed the while() loop in `playGame` to an if(). The `Scanner read` was from an earlier attempt where I was using `while(hasNext())` conditional and `next()` to read chars.